# Prometheus Data persistence and AlertManager Email Config

Tags: cadvisor, prometheus

I have a problem with Prometheus retaining data. I exporters that export metrics to Prometheus and i use prom dash to represent the data. But when i restart Prometheus i lose all the data of my metrics.

And the other problem i have is ,I have configured prometheus to have trigger alerts and i am using alertmanager to send notifications. I have configure alertmanager to send notification of alert to my Email and Flowdock. But I Receive them on flowdock but not on my mail.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

> But when i restart Prometheus i lose all the data of my metrics.

Prometheus stores data in the directory configured by the `-storage.local.path` flag which defaults to `data`. Make sure that's not being deleted between runs.

> I have configure alertmanager to send notification of alert to my Email and Flowdock. But I Receive them on flowdock but not on my mail.

Can you share your configuration? Have you configured a SMTP server and `-notification.smtp.smarthost` per http://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/alertmanager/#email?

Comment: i have set up a post fix null client using the following configuration "inet_interfaces = all", mynetworks = my ip, and i have specified the the flag -notification.smtp.smarthost=localhost:25 
and i get the following error
dial tcp 127.0.0.1:25: connection refused

Comment: Your postfix isn't running then, check the logs for why.

Comment: I got past that. my postfix was not running properly. But now again my alerts are getting rejected saying the receipt is from an unkown host. so i am trying to create authentication as of now.